# When does Enumberable's each_slice method begin to make sense for large arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am working with an array that contains about 400,000+ items. I was looking through Enumerables `each_slice` method on the ruby docs and was wondering to myself if it would make any difference in using it for an array of this size.

According to Rails documentation:

> 1.2 Retrieving Multiple Objects in Batches We often need to iterate over a large set of records, as when we send a newsletter to a large
>   set of users, or when we export data.
>
> This may appear straightforward:
>
> ```
> # This is very inefficient when the users table has thousands of rows. 
> User.all.each do |user|   
>   NewsMailer.weekly(user).deliver_now 
> end
> ```
>
> But
>   this approach becomes increasingly impractical as the table size
>   increases, since User.all.each instructs Active Record to fetch the
>   entire table in a single pass, build a model object per row, and then
>   keep the entire array of model objects in memory. Indeed, if we have a
>   large number of records, the entire collection may exceed the amount
>   of memory available.
>
> Rails provides two methods that address this problem by dividing
>   records into memory-friendly batches for processing. The first method,
>   find_each, retrieves a batch of records and then yields each record to
>   the block individually as a model. The second method, find_in_batches,
>   retrieves a batch of records and then yields the entire batch to the
>   block as an array of models.
>
> The find_each and find_in_batches methods are intended for use in the
>   batch processing of a large number of records that wouldn't fit in
>   memory all at once. If you just need to loop over a thousand records
>   the regular find methods are the preferred option.

Based on this documentation, if I have more than 1,000 array items, would I then start to look into `each_slice`? Also, how do I know by what number I should split it up to help save memory? Is there a way to figure this out?

Comment: That documentation is for ActiveRecord and has nothing to do with `Enumerable#each_slice`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @muistooshort. I figured that they were the same though. Both of them act similarly do they not. They slice an array in batches and then do something with it. Don't they?

Comment: The [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches) in question discusses [`find_each` and `find_in_batches`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html), both of which operate on ActiveRecord models and relations. They don't operate on arrays.